# Scope of Python variables in this case - Difference between Enclosing and Local Variable

Tags: python

I am confused about the scope of python variables. How is this working

Consider the following example

```
i = 12
if i==12 :
    str = "is equal"
else:
    str = "NOT"
print str  //Prints is equal - recognized the string str
```

The variable `str` is only in the scope of if statement and its scope is lost at the else statement. Since there is no hoisting in python. I am confused how this example works.I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules) post and it states that Variables are scoped in the Following order

> 1-L (local variables are given preference)
>
> 2-E (Enclosing variables)
>
> 3-G (Global variables)
>
> 4-B (Builtin)

My question is what is the difference between Enclosing variable and local variable ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The variable `str` is only in the scope of if statement and its scope is lost at the else statement.

Nope. Python is function scoped, not block scoped. Entering an `if` block doesn't create a new scope, so the `str` variable is still in scope for the `print`.

Enclosing variables are variables from functions enclosing a given function. They occur when you have closures:

```
def f():
    x = 3
    def g():
        print x  # enclosing variable
    g()
```

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't have general block scope for, only function scope (with some additional weirdness for cases like `class` declarations). Any name assigned within a function will remain valid for the life of the function.

Enclosing scope applies when nesting function declarations, e.g.:

```
def foo(a):
    def bar(b):
        return a + b
    return bar
```

So in this case, `foo(1)(2)` will create a `bar` whose enclosing scope is a `foo` call with `a == 1`, then call `bar(2)`, which will see `a` as `1`.

Enclosing scope also applies to `lambda` functions; they can read variables available in the scope surrounding the point where `lambda` was used, so for something like this:

```
 val_to_key = {...}  # Some dictionary mapping values to sort key values
 mylist.sort(key=lambda x: val_to_key[x])
```

`val_to_key` is available; it wouldn't be in scope inside the `sort` function, but the `lambda` function binds the enclosing scope at declaration time and can therefore use `val_to_key`.